# Why is swapping the pointers more efficient than copying the content of an array of strings?

Tags: c, pointers, copy, compare-and-swap

I've recently found a comment [How I can make a string array interchange it's components with a swap function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54534509/how-i-can-make-a-string-array-interchange-its-components-with-a-swap-function) which was considered as best answer regarding swapping content of an array of string,however I don't quite understand why swapping using functions such as `strncpy` or `strcpy` is less efficient than swapping the pointers.

P.S:I know that it makes more sense to ask the user who gave that best answer,however I don't have enough reputation points yet.

Comment: Think about how many bytes you're copying.

Comment: I don't have to worry about that since the destination,in my case,will always be larger than the source.

Comment: That’s not what I mean.  How many bytes are potentially swapping when you swap the contents vs. swapping the pointers?

Comment: Does the number of bytes potentially swapped by content usually differ from the one where bytes are swapped by pointers?

Comment: Pointers are a small fixed size (usually 4 or 8 bytes). Swapping two pointers is probably faster than swapping the contents of two arbitrarily large arrays. Fewer bytes is less work...

Comment: Do you know the concept of pointers?

Comment: If you have a fixed array of strings, then you can only use `strcpy` since there are no pointers. E.g. `char arr[100][80];`

Comment: More or less.I mainly know that they store the memory addresses of variables.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie what if I have an array of char pointers?

Comment: Then you should swap the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

strcpy and strncpy will copy each bytes from one memory location to another. To swap content you will have to do this 3 times: firstString to tempBuffer, secongString to firstString then buffer to secondString, what is clearly not really efficient.
But if you manipulate pointers, only the pointers (not the full content) have to be permutated.

In other words, strcpy method will be less efficient as soon as the total size of firstString+secondString will be bigger than twice the size of a pointer (generally 2x4 Bytes but depends on the processor architecture)

Comment: Plus you have no guarantee that one string will fit in the allotted space of the other,